# Spliting debian package - how to handle files correctly?

Tags: build, debian, packaging, deb

I am trying to split debian package to smaller packages.

Original package `MyPackage-1.0.deb` was split to few smaler packages (`MyPackage-2.0.deb`, `MyPackage-config-2.0.deb`).

The `MyPackage-1.0.deb` contained all files, during split I moved all files from directory */etc* to package `MyPackage-config-2.0.deb`.

`dpkg-buildpackage` process was without errors.

When I try upgrade by `apt-get upgrade` i get this message.

```
Unpacking MyPackage-config (from .../MyPackage-config-2.0.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/MyPackage-config-2.0.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/MyPackage.conf', which is also in package MyPackage 1.0
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

The package did not install unitil I forced it by 
`apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" upgrade`

In file `debian/control` there is:

```
Source: MyPackage
Section: metapackages
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Just Me <me@example.com>
Standards-Version: 3.9.3
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 4)

Package: MyPackage
Architecture: i386
Conflicts: gnumeric
Pre-depends: MyPackage-config
Depends: libreoffice-common
Description: This package

Package: MyPackage-config
Essential: yes
Architecture: i386
Depends: openssh-server
Description: config files
```

How should I split packages to prevent the error?

Comment: You probably did not want the `Pre-Depends` but just a plain `Depends`. I don't recall ever having a need for `Pre-Depends` and I would be surprised that your package requires it...

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to add these lines to MyPackage-config:

```
Breaks: MyPackage (<< 2.0)
Replaces: MyPackage (<< 2.0)
```

This tells dpkg not to allow MyPackage 1.0 and MyPackage-config 2.0 to be installed at the same time (cause, obviously, they would both want to own `/etc/MyPackage.conf`), and also that it's ok for MyPackage-config 2.0 to take over some of the files previously owned by MyPackage 1.0.

See http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html for in-depth information.

As an unrelated aside, having "Essential: yes" on MyPackage-config is probably a bad idea.